# prove $S_u(A)⊆\bar A$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let A be a subset of $R$. Let us call $p$ an upper sticking point of $A$ if there is some subset $B ⊆ A$ such that $p = supB$. Let us write $S_u(A)$ for the set of all upper sticking points of $A$. it is always true that $A ⊆ S_u(A)$, since any $a ∈ A$ is the supremum of the one-pointsubset ${a}⊆ A$. Prove that $S_u(A)⊆ \bar A$, and give an example to show that the equality $S_u(A) =\bar A$ does not hold in general

Comment: i was trying to show $S_u(A)$ contains A and have some limit points of A. I that the right way

Comment: You asked the same question in this other post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967791/prove-that-s-ua-%E2%8A%86-a, apart from what I think was a mistake in the other statement ($A$ instead of $\overline A$)

Comment: I should have edit that question. LOL

Answer (score 0):

If $p \in S_u(A)$ you know that you can approximate $p$ by points in $A$ so that $p \in \overline A$. To get a counterexample, consider the collection $\frac 1 n$ for $n>0$.

Comment: i know it is true $S_u(A) ⊆ \bar A $, i have no idea how to prove it

Comment: If $p \in S_u(A)$ then $p = \sup B$ for some $B \subset A$. Then, for each $n \in \mathbb N$ you can find some $b_n \in B$ with $p-\frac 1 n < b_n \leq p$. Such a $b_n$ exists by definition of the supremum. Now the $b_n$ converge to $p$ such that $p \in \overline A$ since each $b_n$ is an element of $A$.